# How to access button in different listview rows?

Tags: android, listview, view, custom-adapter

I'm trying to change the color of buttons in the rows of listview by clicking a button. Here I've a listview composed of 25 rows and each rows contains a button. I've used custom adapter for listview to place button in each row. I like to know how to do following things:

1. Click on a button and its color is changed.
2. After step (1) the onClickListener also change the color of the left-over buttons in the listview to normal.
3. The above two steps should happen to all of the buttons means if any of the button is clicked then it should be colored and remaining will turn back to normal.

the listview is like

---

### Button 1

---

### Button 2

---

### Button 3

---

### Button 4

Comment: add your work so far!

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please show your adapter

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your Button from Adapter. Follow it -

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private List<TestList> list;

    public TestAdapter(Context ctx, List<TestList> list){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TestList getItem(int position) {

        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        }

        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setText(list.get(position));


        return  convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick listener for button in your custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private List<CustomList> list;

    public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, List<CustomList> list){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomList getItem(int position) {

        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        }

        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setText(list.get(position));

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                \\change color here
            }
        });

        return  convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the similar adapter but it only changes the color of the clicked button but doesn't turn back the other buttons back to normal.